# Index error of CSV List in Python, even after getting output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

This is simple program of reading the csv file in form of list, Program is able to print as per index but at last there is a index error

```py
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r in reader:
        lis = list(r)
        print (lis)
        file_dat  = lis[0]
        file_no   = lis[1]
        content    = lis[2]
        print (file_dat)
        print ("File Data Read Successful")
f.close()
```

and the output i get of this program is

```py
['ASFDASD', '2019-10-19', 'horse']
ASFDASD
File Data Read Successful
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KIRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\direction.py", line 14, in <module>
    file_dat  = lis[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: first check if `list` is not empty and has length of `3`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is reading the last line of the input file as a completely empty line, resulting in an empty list. This empty list is printed out right below `File Data Read Successful`.

Maybe check to make sure the list isn't empty after you print it but before you assign it?

```py
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r in reader:
        lis = list(r)
        if(lis.len() = 3):
          print (lis)
          file_dat  = lis[0]
          file_no   = lis[1]
          content    = lis[2]
          print (file_dat)
          print ("File Data Read Successful")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you last *lis* is empty and you are trying to access lis[0].
check first that the list is not empty by `if lis:`